# Young's experiment: with and without lens

Tags: optics, interference

To my knowledge, there are two possible arrangements to realize the Young experiment: with or without a lens between the holes (or the slits) and the screen
[image]
[image]
In the first case the optical path difference is $\delta = n_0 a x/f'$, in the second it's $\delta = n_0 a x/D$, where $n_0$ is the refraction index of the medium in which the system is immersed, $a$ is the distance between the holes or the slits and $x$ the position on the screen. I guess that I understand intuitively why it's $f'$ in one case and $D$ in the other, but I'd like a more rigorous explanation.